# How can the Individual components be deployed in Digital Experience?

Tags: community, lightning-community, digital-experience

Using metadata api, I could find brandingSet, CommunityThemeDefinition and CommunityTemplateDefinition for Digital Experience app. But I need to know if all components can be separately deployed in an ExperienceBundle type like brandingSet, themes, config, routes and views. or we need to overwrite entire ExperienceBundle with any change in it's components.

Comment: It is a single "blob" of data that must be deployed together from what I can see.

Comment: If you enable `enableExperienceBundleMetadata` you can retrieve whole community not as a blob but as metadata folder with json files. Not sure if from here you are able to pick just some components.

Comment: Another possible solution would be to use in Builder>Settings>Developer Export functionality.

Comment: By "blob" I simply meant a collection of metadata. I did not mean the old site.com literal blob. While the experience bundle includes lots of separate JSON files for routes, views etc. they are related together by naming AND unique IDs generated and referenced within them. All these relationships must be maintained and from what I see this means an all-or-nothing deployment.

Comment: Yes, after enabling the flag, I am able to retrieve all subfolders with individual components. But if we change later on, something in brandingSet or maybe theme etc, is our only option, is to overwrite ExperienceBundle entirely or specific changes could also be deployed ?
They have documentation for brandingSet, CommunityTemplateDefintion or CommunityThemeDefinition, but not sure if it can be used or not as I am not able to see any thing in workbench retrieval using package xml with these ?

Comment: I personally believe you should be able to deploy the branding set separately, since it is a separate metadata element, but the whole experience bundle is treated as a single metadata item from the deployment perspective.